# Check if file is included on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that includes (and it must include) a JS file that has the following line in it:

```
$('.container').perfectScrollbar();

... more essential code ...
```

When I go to the page, the console gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function
```

This is because I don't include the file required for the perfectScrollbar plugin (because the page doesn't need it).

How do I check to see if the perfectScrollbar plugin is loaded or not. i.e, something like:

```
if (isIncluded) {
    $('.container').perfectScrollbar();
}
```

Comment: If $().perfectScrollbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method will be a property of `jQuery.fn`.

Thus you can do:

```
if( typeof $.fn.perfectScrollbar === 'function'){
     /* can use the plugin */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test directly for the presence of the function itself, like this:

```
if ($('.container').perfectScrollbar) {
    $.fn.perfectScrollbar();
}
```

Comment: Don't bother duplicating the query for `$(".container")`, just check for `$.fn.perfectScrollbar`